# Difference between "hear" and "hear out"?

Tags: phrasal-verbs

I'm totally confused why in some sentences the phrasal verb "hear out" is used instead of "hear".

For example:

> Stewie: Look, I’m going to propose something and I need you to hear me out. Will you promise me you’ll do that?

Comment: Have you looked these up? Please take a look at learner's and other kinds of dictionaries listed [here](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/a/739/3395), and then edit your post to include the newly found information if your uncertainties persist.

Answer (score 3):

To hear someone out is to let them speak all that they have to say, without interrupting.

[Hear out (Cambridge)](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/hear-someone-out)